# Adding Xlwings autofilter returns an error

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Hello I have a problem when I add filtering code below

Everything is okay before adding the filter code

```py
# 필터를 적용할 시트 선택
sheet = inventory_workbook.sheets['Raw data']

# 필터를 적용할 열 범위 선택
column_range = sheet.range('D:D')

# 필터 적용
column_range.autofilter(1)  # 헤더 행 포함 여부 (1은 포함)

# 필터 옵션 설정 (값이 'ECP', 'FCP', 'FMP', 'MMU', 'RRH', 'UMP'인 행만 표시)
column_range.filter('ECP', 'FCP', 'FMP', 'MMU', 'RRH', 'UMP')`
```

When added the following error occurs;

```
Exception has occurred: com_error -2147352567,'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565)
```

I don't know how solve this error
Help me.........

I've upgraded Xlwings and tried uninstall/re-install

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to do something like the following, Filter column D with the following cells selected;
`('ECP', 'FCP', 'FMP', 'MMU', 'RRH', 'UMP')`

[image]

You'd need to use the Xlwings api to add the `autofilter` and set the criterial in a list.

```
import xlwings as xw


xlfile = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    inventory_workbook = xw.Book(xlfile)

    ### 필터를 적용할 시트 선택
    sheet = inventory_workbook.sheets['Raw data']

    ### 필터를 적용할 열 범위 선택
    column_range = sheet.range('D:D')

    ### 필터 옵션 설정 (값이 'ECP', 'FCP', 'FMP', 'MMU', 'RRH', 'UMP'인 행만 표시)
    ### Set filter options (value is 'ECP', 'FCP', 'FMP', 'MMU', 'RRH', 'UMP' only display rows that are
    # column_range.filter('ECP', 'FCP', 'FMP', 'MMU', 'RRH', 'UMP')
    criteria_list = ["ECP", "FCP", "FMP", "MMU", "RRH", "UMP"]

    ### First value 1 is the Field
    ### 2nd value is the list of criteria
    ### Last value 7 is the Operator setting, 7 = xlFilterValues
    column_range.api.AutoFilter(1, criteria_list, 7)
    sheet.show_autofilter = True  # may be optional

    inventory_workbook.save('out_foo.xlsx')
```